# pgsql query to return single row to find the total count of diff columns on the same date

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains discount codes coupon_code and its vendor name.
eg: coupon_code: abc vendor: newyork
    coupon_code: def vendor: usa
Another table has order details which contains date,coupon_code,order_number
eg:

> date: 2012-04-07 coupon_code:abc  order_number:1
>       date: 2012-04-08 coupon_code:abc  order_number:2
>       date: 2012-04-08 coupon_code:def  order_number:3
>       date: 2012-04-09 coupon_code:abc  order_number:4

How can i get the total number of codes used for each day?
expected result

> eg:  date         newyork[abc]  usa[def]
>        2012-04-07     1              0
>        2012-04-08     1              1
>        2012-04-09     1              0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select date, 
       count(case when coupon_code = 'abc' then 1 else null end) as newyork,
       count(case when coupon_code = 'def' then 1 else null end) as usa
From tbl
group by date
```

Comment: thankz it works.. but how can i join both tables using discount_code and get the above result with column name as newyork_abc without hardcoding the name.

Comment: post your table structure and sample data in well formated